# proof with complex integration by u-substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-writing

> If $f$ is continuous in $[0,\pi]$, use the substitution $u = \pi - x$ to show that $\int_0^{\pi} xf(\sin x)dx = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} f(\sin x)dx$

Not having much idea where to begin, I naively try just substituting the given term in like so:

$u = \pi - x \Leftrightarrow x = \pi - u$, so I have

$\int_0^{\pi} xf(\sin x)dx = \int_0^{-\pi} (\pi-u)f(\sin u)du$

The best I could come up with then is

$ \pi\int_0^{-\pi} f(\sin u)du - \int_0^{-\pi} uf(\sin u)du$

But this is about as far as I get, which doesn't look very far to me. The "$f$ is continuous in ..." bit of the problem statement makes me think I should be looking to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but none of the forms there look promising to my un-practiced eyes.

Any guidance at all would be much appreciated. Also, this is not homework, but is test prep.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. You're already on half way. Call the integral you look for $I$ and observe it is also present on the right side.
2. I think the limits of integration after substition are swapped.

Comment: if I call $\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\pi} f(\sin x)dx$ $I$, I don't know that I actually can see that $I$ present on the right side after that substitution step, beyond the sense that I _trust_ that it is indeed equal to the LHS term. I won't be offended by a bit of hand-holding...I haven't taken a math class in  8 years.

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$I=\int_0^\pi x f(\sin x)dx$$

As you have found,

$$I=\int_0^{-\pi}(\pi-u)f(\sin u)du=-\int_0^\pi(u-\pi)f(\sin u)du=-I+\pi\int_0^\pi f(\sin x)dx$$

Comment: I don't follow $\int_0^{-a} f(x) = -\int_0^a f(x)$ I know changing the sign of the integral swaps the limits...

Comment: For anyone else that might have been confused by this step, I believe the explanation is that the property $\int_0^{-a}f(x) = -\int_0^{a}f(x)$ holds for even functions. Someone correct me if I'm wrong!